# how to show content of bytearray in pydev debugger?

Tags: python, eclipse, ide, pydev

Is there a way to make eclipse+pydev show the content of a bytearray?

I have something like :

```
bytearray(b'\x1a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

but on eclipse it looks like this :

[image]

It would make debugging much easier if I could look into these..

Thanks,

weasel